# Double Integral as Iterated Integral: Integrand changes and I don't understand reasoning behind it.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, iterated-integrals

I need to compute the integral $\int \int_{R} y e^{xy}dA$ for $[0,3]\times [0,1]$.

In the solutions, it has the double integral rewritten as $\int\int_{R} y e^{xy} dA = \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{1} x e^{xy} dydx$.

I'm assuming that some change of variables has taken place here in order for the integrand to go from $y e^{xy}$ to $x e^{xy}$ but I don't understand exactly how. Could somebody please explain this to me in as detailed a fashion (pictures would be good, but not essential) as possible?

Thank you for your time and patience

Comment: They are not equal..perhaps it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a typo, because $$\int\int_{R} y e^{xy} dA = \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{1} x e^{xy} dy dx$$ is not correct. The correct form is  $$\int\int_{R} y e^{xy} dA = \int_{0}^{3} \int_{0}^{1} y e^{xy} dy dx=\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{3} y e^{xy} dx dy $$

Comment: you can't just treat $x$ and $y$ like dummy variables here and just interchange them?

Comment: On rectangular region, you can interchange the variables because bounds are constant. In general you change the bounds according to the region of integration.

Comment: but it's not correct to let $x=y$ inside the integrand in this particular case?

Comment: You do not put x=y inside the integrand. You may rename your variables  if you wish because as you mentioned earlier these are just dummy variables.